# Having trouble getting my HTML onload to call my JS function

Tags: javascript, html, function, onload

1. I have a function that should be called whenever my html page loads. The `<body>` tag should call the startAdPage() function. However, nothing at all happens. I am not completely sure why. Any suggestions? Here is the `<body>` call in my HTML page

   ```
   <body onload="startAdPage();">
   ```
2. Next, here is my startAdPage() function, as well as the two functions it calls. Those two aren't completely finished yet. One of them is supposed to create a small image gallery slide show. The other is supposed to create a countdown from 10 - 1 before displaying a separate web page. Neither work yet, so any advice on them would also be appreciated, though they aren't my main focus yet.

   ```
      function startAdPage(){

              setInterval(changeAd(), 2000);

              setInterval(startCountdown(), 1000);

       }
   ```
3. Here is `changeAd()`

   ```
      function changeAd() {

          for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++){

             document.images[0].src = "images/pic" + intNumber + ".jpg";

          }

       }
   ```
4. Lastly, `startCountdown()`. I haven't made the webpage that I said this function calls yet

   ```
        function startCountdown() {
              window.alert('Test');

              for(var i = 10; i >= 1; i++){

                 document.getElementById("countdown").value = i;

              }
           }
   ```

Comment: You're passing the *return value* of each function to `setInterval()`. Pass a function reference to `setInterval()`, e.g., `setInterval(changeAd, 2000)` (no `()` on the `changeAd`).

Comment: Well that made function call properly, but it made my page crash.... I think its because of my countdown function. Could that be right?

Comment: It's probably `for(var i = 10; i >= 1; i++){`. You want to decrement the `i`: `i--`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
          document.images[0].src = "images/pic" + intNumber + ".jpg";
```

You refer to intNumber but you should be using i instead. So change the above to

```
document.images[0].src = "images/pic" + i + ".jpg";
```

and your function will be called.

You should consider removing the onload in the body tag and do a

```
 window.onload = startAdPage;
```

instead - to keep your html and Js logic separate.

Also, your countdown logic is wrong - you want to decrement i, not increment:

```
  var i = 10; i>0; i--
```

Comment: Where would I put the window.onload = startAdPage;?

Comment: it's part of your js - so just put it anywhere in your js - it assigns an event handler to the window object that basically tells the page to execute the function once the page is loaded

Comment: @Historiun - You might use `window.addEventListener('load', startAdPage)` instead of `window.onload`. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/3zyx9kby/ ([Order doesn't matter, as functions are hoisted.](http://jsfiddle.net/3zyx9kby/1/))

Comment: @BirgitMartinelle - I know this is probably a silly question, but wont putting it anywhere in the .js file make it load on every page that also uses that .js? Because it has functions that I use on multiple pages

Comment: yes that function would then be called whenever a page loads that uses that JS
@Historiun, addEventListener is only supported in IE9 and up as far as I know - since I don't see any jQuery I suppose IE legacy should be supported hence window.onload suggestion

Comment: [Thank god that usage of IE8 and lower is almost negligible these days.](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201308-201408) The recommendation is to use `window.attachEvent` for that browser version instead, as well.